# Linq: Get all values of a group by in csv-format

Tags: c#, linq

I have a csv- file which looks like:

ID, Priority, Value

1 , 300     , 0.90

2 , 400     , 0.50

This file I open in C# and now I try to:

- Order the file by column value
- group the file by column priority
- write result afterwards back to an other csv-file

I've tried to use Linq. 
The ordering works, but now I have problems using the group by. 
My code is the following:

```
  var p = @"C:\temp\Values.csv";
  var lines = File.ReadAllLines(p);
  var data = lines.Skip(1);

  var sorted = data.Select(line => new
  {
      SortKey = Double.Parse(line.Split(',')[2]),
      GroupValues = Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[1]),
      Line = line
  })
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.SortKey)
               .GroupBy(x => x.GroupValues)
               .Select(x => new
               {
                   key = x.Key,
                   values = x.Select(xc => xc.Line)
               })
               .Select(x => x.values).FirstOrDefault();

  File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\sorted.csv", 
                       lines.Take(1).Concat(sorted));
```

Of course, ".FirstOrDefault()" within the last select returns only one value... But I have tried so much and I do not manage to get the values the right way...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is a class for this CSV and a CustomComparer to mutch? Because with a class we coulg dropt the line and split and deserialize csv to list object . Order them and write it back. in a clear and bullet proof way. You will need a class with 3 fieldw, a comparer on 2 fields and an external library like CSV helper. But it will be a robust solution.

Comment: What is the *desired outcome* (i.e. final csv format), please?

Comment: The desired outcome shoud be a csv file which looks like the one in the question: but the rows should be ordered by the value and additionally grouped by the priority

Comment: @Kimmy: `GroupBy` *aggregates* the values, in general case you'll never come up with the *same csv format*. Are you looking for `ThenBy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear, what is the desired outcome; for instance for

```
   ID, Priority, Value
    1,      300,  0.90
    2,      400,  0.50
    3,      300,  0.80 
    4,      500,  0.70
```

according to your requirements (*ordering* followed by *grouping*) you'll get the structure below:

```
Priority (key) Items
     400       {(2, 400, 0.50)}                 # group has 1 item
     300       {(1, 300, 0.90), (3, 300, 0.80)} # group has 2 items 
     500       {(4, 500, 0.70)}
```

If you want to turn this to comma separated lines (please, note, that you are going to have different values in different lines)

```
     2, 400, 0.50               # 3 columns : from group with 1 item
     1, 300, 0.90, 3, 300, 0.80 # 6 columns : from group with 2 items
     4, 500, 0.70
```

You can use the code below

```
var data = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\temp\Values.csv")
  .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // To be on the safe side
  .Skip(1)                                         // Skip title  
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))                  
  .Select(items => new {
     ID = long.Parse(items[0]), 
     Priority = int.Parse(items[1]), 
     Value = Decimal.Parse(items[2]),
   })
   .OrderBy(item => item.Value)                    // order by Value
   .GroupBy(item => item.Priority)                 // group by priority 
   .Select(group => string.Join(",", group         // turn group to comma separated
      .Select(item => string.Join(",", item.ID, item.Priority, item.Value))));

File
  .WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\sorted.csv", data);
```

If you actually want to **sort** items *with* equal `Value` by `Priority`, for instance for given

```
 ID, Priority, Value
  2,      400,  0.50
  4,      500,  0.70
  1,      300,  0.70
  3,      300,  0.80
```

you want

```
 ID, Priority, Value
  2,      400,  0.50
  1,      300,  0.70 # in case of tie (same Values) order by priority
  4,      500,  0.70
  3,      300,  0.80
```

you *don't want* any `GroupBy`, but `ThenBy`:

```
var data = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\temp\Values.csv")
  .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // To be on the safe side
  .Skip(1)                                         // Skip title  
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))                  
  .Select(items => new {
     ID = long.Parse(items[0]), 
     Priority = int.Parse(items[1]), 
     Value = Decimal.Parse(items[2]),
   })
  .OrderBy(item => item.Value)    // order by Value
  .ThenBy(item => item.Priority)  // ! In case of tie, order by priority
  .Select(item => $"{item.ID},{item.Priority},{item.Value}"); 

File
  .WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\sorted.csv", new string[] {
     "ID", "Priority", "Value"}.Concat(data)
);
```

Comment: Tanks a million for your answer! :-) My intense was to build comma separated lines. Your first code statement was exactly what I was trying to do. I simple changed Join(",", group....) to Join("\n",group,...), so that every line is written to one line in the csv file

Comment: @Kimmy: You are welcome! Actually, you want an usual *ordering* (since you split groups back into items); typical way for it is `SelectMany`: `SelectMany(group => group).Select(item => string.Join(",", item.ID, item.Priority, item.Value));`

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I've adjusted your first statement and it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

You need Select First() in the group. Something like below.

```
        var p = @"C:\temp\Values.csv";
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(p);
        var data = lines.Skip(1);

        var NotOrdered = data.Select(line => new
        {
            Value = Double.Parse(line.Split(',')[2]),
            Priority = Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[1]),
            ID = Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[0])
        });

        var sorted = NotOrdered
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.Priority);


        var sortedAndConcatedString = sorted.Select(x => x.ID.ToString() + "," + 
        x.Priority.ToString() + "," + x.Value.ToString()).ToArray();

        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\sorted.csv",
                             sortedAndConcatedString);
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer!
But right now: if my input csv file is

ID, Priority, Value

1 , 300 , 0.90

2 , 300 , 0.50

The return value would be 

ID, Priority, Value

1 , 300 , 0.90

So only the first member of each group is written to the csv file (Which obviously comes from .First()). 

Do you know a way, how it is possible to write all group members to the csv-file?

Comment: If you need all members then there is no need to do group by at all. I have edited the answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment and edit! :-) I did not know anything (and never really heard) about then by. But I was used to group by from SQL and I thought it would work the same way  in linq

Comment: No worries :-) Then by is similar to second order by clause in SQL. Something similar to above LINQ would "select Id, Priority, Value from Sorted order by Value DESC, Priority"